# AWS EKS: Issues with nameserver

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, dns

I have an `aws eks` cluster, with `10.10.0.0/16` Service IPv4 range.
When I would like to see the nameservers inside of pods, I get a strange nameserver configuration:

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 172.20.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local eu-central-1.compute.internal
options ndots:5
```

So instead of getting `10.10.0.10` I'm getting as you can see `172.20.0.10`. What should be change to get proper nameserver? So at the very end all pods which will be created, should use `10.10.0.10` as their nameserver, like:

```
nameserver 10.10.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local eu-central-1.compute.internal
options ndots:5
```

---

Here is additional info:

Output of: `kubectl get service kube-dns -n kube-system`

```
NAME       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
kube-dns   ClusterIP   10.10.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   3h14m
```

Output of: `kubectl -n kube-system get endpoints kube-dns`

```
NAME       ENDPOINTS                                                 AGE
kube-dns   10.0.80.105:53,10.0.96.46:53,10.0.80.105:53 + 1 more...   3h15m
```

Comment: Seems like that might be an effect of "ClusterFirst" DNS policy applied by default, do you get the same output if you change the policy to "Default"?

Comment: This is the default config for EKS. Is something not working properly? What's the actual issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a default config. That uses coredns.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? i've been dealing with something really similar